# TSQL Insert into with CTE, how to do it?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm struggling with the problem below.

I have written CTE where I calculate quantity of headcount in year,mth and cumulatively.

My code:

```
with HRdataCTE as 
    (
Select 
    BusinessEntityID,
    HireDate,
    Month(HireDate) as HireMth,
    Datename(M,HireDate) as HireMthName,
    DATEPART(M,HireDate) as HireMth2,
    YEAR(HireDate) as HireYear

from HumanResources.Employee
    )

select distinct
    HireYear,
    HireMth,
    HireMthName,
    COUNT(*) over (partition by HireYear, HireMthName) as MthQuantity,
    COUNT(*) over (partition by HireYear) as YearQuantity,
    COUNT(*) over (partition by HireYear order by HireMth) as YearMhtCumulatively
from HRdataCTE
```

If I wanna create a view in SQL it will be ok, but suppose I have a table like this:

```
create table HRanalysis (
    HireYear int,
    HireMth int,
    HireMthName varchar(20),
    MthQuantity int,
    YearQuantity int,
    YearMhtCumulatively int)
```

and I wanna insert my code from CTE to this table I have an error about semicolon (?) between insert into statement and CTE.

```
Insert into HRanalysis(
    HireYear,
    HireMth,
    HireMthName,
    MthQuantity,
    YearQuantity,
    YearMhtCumulatively)
    ;
with HRdataCTE as 
    (
Select 
    BusinessEntityID,
    HireDate,
    Month(HireDate) as HireMth,
    Datename(M,HireDate) as HireMthName,
    DATEPART(M,HireDate) as HireMth2,
    YEAR(HireDate) as HireYear

from HumanResources.Employee
    )

select distinct
    HireYear,
    HireMth,
    HireMthName,
    COUNT(*) over (partition by HireYear, HireMthName) as MthQuantity,
    COUNT(*) over (partition by HireYear) as YearQuantity,
    COUNT(*) over (partition by HireYear order by HireMth) as YearMhtCumulatively
from HRdataCTE
```

Error message:
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 20
Incorrect syntax near ';'.
It is this error between insert into statement and CTE

So How to put this CTE to a table HRanalysis? Please help me

Comment: `;` is a statement terminator, it's not part of the `WITH` (it goes at the end of *all* your statements).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax is that need to put `INSERT INTO` in front of `SELECT`

```
;with HRdataCTE as 
(
    Select 
    BusinessEntityID,
    HireDate,
    Month(HireDate) as HireMth,
    Datename(M,HireDate) as HireMthName,
    DATEPART(M,HireDate) as HireMth2,
    YEAR(HireDate) as HireYear
    from HumanResources.Employee
)
Insert into HRanalysis(
    HireYear,
    HireMth,
    HireMthName,
    MthQuantity,
    YearQuantity,
    YearMhtCumulatively)
select distinct
    HireYear,
    HireMth,
    HireMthName,
    COUNT(*) over (partition by HireYear, HireMthName) as MthQuantity,
    COUNT(*) over (partition by HireYear) as YearQuantity,
    COUNT(*) over (partition by HireYear order by HireMth) as YearMhtCumulatively
from HRdataCTE
```

Comment: OMGGGG i really really thank you. I have spent about 4 hours to resolve this problem :)

Comment: Small quibble, but it is also important to note that the CTE definition needs to be made prior to any statement that will be consuming it. In this case, the `INSERT` (including the `SELECT` that defines the data to be inserted) is the CTE-consuming statement.